# WPF File association Relative Path

Tags: c#, wpf

I recently added file association for my WPF application. Everything is working fine but I have few files in a folder where my .exe is present. At some places I am using relative path to access these files.

When I click my .eg(Associated extension) file and my application starts. But when I try to access the files in the folder relative to my exe inside the application , the relative path is shown from the location of .eg.

I have fixed this by changing them to absolute path for now but I am curious on why this is happening and is there a better way to fix this.

Comment: Get the path/folder location (there are different ways to do that, one that is being independent on your actual project/prgram type is to query the location of the executing assembly - the executing program) of your exe and use this together with the exe-relative path to your files to form an absolute path to the files.

Comment: Sure Thanks. This is how i am accessing it now Path.GetFullPath(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "..\\image\\text.png");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

in your `App.xaml.cs` (there are multiple ways to simulate main() method in WPF, any one of them would work)

after this all the relative path you use will be relative to your main exe's folder.

Comment: I tired the line above in my App.xaml.cs and got this exception: 
 [System.IO.IOException] = {System.IO.IOException: The directory name is invalid.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(String path)
   at System.Environment.set_CurrentDirectory(String value)                                      I got idea from your code and tried this : Environment.CurrentDirectory = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @PrimeOfKnights um..interesting. base directory should give you the same path as well not sure why the first one didnt work. but glad it worked out in the end